# differential form and cylindrical coordinate

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Problem.

> If $r, \theta, z$ are the cylindrical coordinate functions on $\mathbb
> > R^3$ , then $x = r\cos\theta, y = r\sin\theta, z = z$. Compute the
>   volume element dx dy dz of $\mathbb R^3$ in cylindrical coordinates.
>   (That is, express dx dy dz in terms of the functions $r, \theta, z$,
>   and their differentials.)

My solution.

$dx = \cos\theta dr - r\sin\theta d\theta$

$dy = \sin\theta dr + r\cos\theta d\theta$

$dz = dz$

$$ dx\wedge dy\wedge dz = ... = rdrd\theta dz$$

Actually, these steps are from internet or answer page. I have no idea of how to connect $dxdydz$ and $drd\theta dz$. I don't know why $wedge$ operator is done.

Additionally, I want to know how to convert spherical coordinate using 1-form.

Comment: Take a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables

Comment: Wedge product is distributive and skew-symmetric (i.e., $dr\wedge d\theta = -d\theta\wedge dr$). So you'll find that $dx \wedge dy = r\,dr\wedge d\theta$.

Comment: My question is why wedge product is needed.

Comment: @rlartiga, I saw it already.

Comment: as an intro on "why wedge product", start by learning about bi-vectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Begin with coordinate transformation:

$ ds^2 = g_{ab}dx^adx^b $

$ = g_{ab}\frac{\partial x^a}{\partial \zeta^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial x^b}{\partial \zeta^{\beta}} d\zeta^{\alpha}d\zeta^{\beta}$

$ = \gamma_{\alpha\beta} d\zeta^{\alpha}d\zeta^{\beta}$

where

$ \gamma_{\alpha\beta}=g_{ab}\frac{\partial x^a}{\partial \zeta^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial x^b}{\partial \zeta^{\beta}} $

This relates the Cartesian metric to the cylindrical metric:

$ g_{ab}=
\begin{pmatrix}
    1       & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 1 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

$ \gamma_{\alpha\beta}=
\begin{pmatrix}
    1       & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & r^2 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

The volume form is given as:

$dV = \sqrt{|det(\gamma_{\alpha\beta})|}d\zeta^{(0)} \land d\zeta^{(1)} \land d\zeta^{(2)} $

$= rd\zeta^{(0)} \land d\zeta^{(1)} \land d\zeta^{(2)} $

$= rdr \land d\theta \land dz $

- note that: $ Adx \land dy \land dz = Adxdydz $ in most shorthand.

Wedge products are used because they allow for one to construct area and volume elements from infinitesimal length elements $ds$. So $dx$ would be an infinitesimal length element, $dx \land dy$ would be an infinitesimal area, and so on.

To convert to spherical coordinates, you would just redefine the second metric as:

$ \gamma_{\alpha\beta}=
\begin{pmatrix}
    1       & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & r^2 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & r^2sin^2(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}$

with $ d\zeta^{(2)} = d\phi$